# Dropdown Div Toggle 2 Different Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have an existing javascript solution that works well, but I came across a new enhancement that requires that a div that I named "alwaysdisplayonselection" to be visible only once a dropdown selection is changed from the default to something else.

Here's the working [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/qt05wa6L/9/)

Here's the HTML code:

```
<select name="my-select" class="js-my-select">
  <option value="nothing" selected>Select Color</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="orange">Orange</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
<div class="js-my-image red"></div>
<div class="js-my-image orange"></div>
<div class="js-my-image yellow"></div>
<div class="js-my-image blue"></div>
<div class="js-my-image green"></div>
<div class="js-my-image alwaysdisplayonselection">This is visible once a selection is made, but invisible once the selection is returned to default, or the first dropdown option with "nothing" value.</div>
```

This is the javascript that toggles between the different Divs:

```
$(function() {
  var $select = $('.js-my-select'),
    $images = $('.js-my-image');

  $select.on('change', function() {
    var value = '.' + $(this).val();
    $images.show().not(value).hide();
  });
});
```

I would appreciate any help getting the "alwaysdisplayonselection" div to only display once and option is selected and hidden once the page is refreshed or the option selected has "nothing" as the value.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) the visibility inside the **change** event:

```
$('.alwaysdisplayonselection').toggle(this.value != 'nothing');
```

Your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qt05wa6L/22/)

```js
var $select = $('.js-my-select'),
    $images = $('.js-my-image');

$select.on('change', function () {
    var value = '.' + $(this).val();
    $images.show().not(value).hide();
    $('.alwaysdisplayonselection').toggle(this.value != 'nothing');
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="my-select" class="js-my-select">
    <option value="nothing" selected>Select Color</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

<div class="js-my-image red"></div>
<div class="js-my-image orange"></div>
<div class="js-my-image yellow"></div>
<div class="js-my-image blue"></div>
<div class="js-my-image green"></div>
<div class="js-my-image alwaysdisplayonselection">This is visible once a selection is made, but invisible once the
    selection is returned to default, or the first dropdown option with "nothing" value.
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesomely simple!  Thanks!